# Why a query takes too long in statistics thread state in AWS Aurora MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, amazon-rds, greatest-n-per-group, aws-aurora

The following query execution too long in statistics state and I couldn't figure out why.

DB engine - `5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2`

DB Size - `db.r5.4xlarge`

Sample Query Profile output

```
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000023 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000155 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000009 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000002 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000003 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000002 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000009 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000035 |
| init                           | 0.000102 |
| System lock                    | 0.000035 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000004 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000003 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000011 |
| statistics                     | 0.224528 |
| preparing                      | 0.000030 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000017 |
| statistics                     | 0.000041 |
| preparing                      | 0.000013 |
| Creating tmp table             | 0.000023 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000013 |
| statistics                     | 0.064207 |
| preparing                      | 0.000035 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.000025 |
| statistics                     | 0.000098 |
| preparing                      | 0.000018 |
| executing                      | 0.000011 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000007 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000251 |
| executing                      | 0.000007 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000003 |
| executing                      | 0.000002 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000526 |
| end                            | 0.000007 |
| query end                      | 0.000013 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000007 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000003 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000004 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000002 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000005 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000002 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.000004 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000010 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000050 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000007 |
| cleaned up                     | 0.000004 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000017 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Query

```
select xo.ITEM, xo.VALUE
from (
         select pi.ITEM, pi.ITEM_GROUP, pi.VALUE
         from TABLE_2 pi
                  inner join (select max(ps.EXPORTED_DATE) as max_expo, ps.ITEM
                              from TABLE_2 ps
                                       inner join (
                                  select max(pp.EFFECTIVE_DATE) max_eff_TABLE_2, pp.ITEM
                                  from TABLE_2 pp
                                  where pp.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '2020/07/17'
                                    and ITEM in
                                        ('20', '30', '40', '50', '110', '120', '320', '520', '720', '820', '920', '321',
                                         '275', '221')
                                  group by ITEM
                              ) a on ps.EFFECTIVE_DATE = a.max_eff_TABLE_2 and ps.ITEM = a.ITEM
                              group by a.ITEM) rr on rr.ITEM = pi.ITEM and rr.max_expo = pi.EXPORTED_DATE) xo

         inner join (
    select ea.ITEM, ea.CUSTOMER_ID, ea.ITEM_GROUP
    from TABLE_1 ea
             inner join (
        select MAX(e.EFFECTIVE_DATE) eat_max_eff, e.ITEM, e.CUSTOMER_ID
        from TABLE_1 e
        where e.CUSTOMER_ID = '20'
          and ITEM in ('20', '30', '40', '50', '110', '120', '320', '520', '720', '820', '920', '321', '275', '221')
          and EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '2020/07/17'
        group by e.ITEM
    ) aa
    where ea.ITEM = (aa.ITEM)
      and ea.CUSTOMER_ID = aa.CUSTOMER_ID
      and ea.EFFECTIVE_DATE = aa.eat_max_eff) lo
                    on lo.ITEM_GROUP = xo.ITEM_GROUP and lo.ITEM = xo.ITEM;
```

Indexes

Table 1

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM T1;
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| T1    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | CUSTOMER_ID    | A         |     3297549 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T1    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            2 | ITEM           | A         |   687374784 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T1    |          0 | PRIMARY      |            3 | EFFECTIVE_DATE | A         |  1314196480 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T1    |          1 | t1_ix_item   |            1 | ITEM           | A         |     2151649 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Table 2

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM TABLE_2;
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_T2rt | T2cked | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| T2    |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | ITEM           | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          0 | PRIMARY               |            2 | ITEM_GROUP     | A         |       14265 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          0 | PRIMARY               |            3 | EFFECTIVE_DATE | A         |    63663076 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          0 | PRIMARY               |            4 | EXPORTED_DATE  | A         |    62464764 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_expo       |            1 | ITEM           | A         |      115823 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_expo       |            2 | EXPORTED_DATE  | A         |    13766454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_eff_date   |            1 | ITEM           | A         |      115823 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_eff_date   |            2 | EFFECTIVE_DATE | A         |    13766454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_eff_ig     |            1 | ITEM           | A         |      115823 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_eff_ig     |            2 | EFFECTIVE_DATE | A         |    13766454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_ix_item_eff_ig     |            3 | ITEM_GROUP     | A         |    68216912 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| T2    |          1 | t2_idx_effective_date |            1 | EFFECTIVE_DATE | A         |       79406 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

According to this: [statistics State in MySQL Processlist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55969/statistics-state-in-mysql-processlist)

I checked the innodb_buffer_pool_size.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "innodb_buffer_pool_size";
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name           | Value       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 96223625216 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
```

In EXPLAIN output rows are minimal (Depends on the Item count in the query. If Item count is 10, the number of rows were 20). Even though the row counts are minimal why the query takes too long in statistics state?

Answer (score 0):

This is "wrong":

```
            SELECT  MAX(e.EFFECTIVE_DATE) eat_max_eff, e.ITEM, e.CUSTOMER_ID
                from  TABLE_1 e
                where  e.CUSTOMER_ID = '20'
                  and  ITEM in (...)
                  and  EFFECTIVE_DATE <= '2020/07/17'
                group by  e.ITEM
```

See "only_full_group_by" for discussion.  In particular, `e.CUSTOMER_ID` will _not necessarily be the id for the `MAX(e.EFFECTIVE_DATE)` that was found.  Please fix that "groupwise-max" problem before further discussion of "statistics".

"Profile" is not the best of tools.  Suggest getting more info via `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and "Optimizer trace".

Comment: Since I'm choosing the EFFECTIVE_DATE of the rows which satisfies the where clause of e.CUSTOMER_ID = '20',  always the SELECT e.CUSTOMER_ID will be 20, isn't it?

Comment: @Vithulan - Yes, `customer_id` will always be 20.  However, `item` is not a single value.  One index can help with 2 things in the where; another index can help with a diff 2.  But there is no possible index to handle all 3 columns _efficiently_.  (Or, am I missing your point?)

Comment: The primary key of that table is `customer_id`, `item` and 'effective_date`. That's what I use now but not sure how efficient that is.